# Count values with the same length

Tags: mysql, count

I need to count all the people with the same name length in mysql table.

Ex:
Andrew, Peter, Lilly, John, Jane, Anne

The result should be 5, since Andrew is the only name that's 6 characters long.

Comment: your question is not the clear ... explain better ... with the same name lenght you 3x 4, 2x 5 and 1 x6

Comment: you mean same length, but peter and jane has different length ?